# C# Web Api xml save issue

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-web-api, save

I've got a strange behaviour with C# Web API and a save of xml.
I've got this test class:

```
public class TestsApiController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Test()
    {
        try
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, "OK!");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, e.Message);
        }

    }

    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Test2()
    {
        try
        {
            string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/bin"),"Backup", string.Concat("test_", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMddHHmmssffff"), ".xml"));

            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>");

            return Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, "Done!");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, e.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

Now the stranger thing: if I invoke Test after Test2 is isn't immediate but It took around 2s to finish. If I invoke Test another one it returns immediate.
I'm trying with local server (IIS Express).

What's wrong?

I tried to save the xml file with `XMLDocument.Save` but the result not change.

I attach the timig from Google Chrome where You can see that TTFB is very high:
[image: Timing]

Comment: in your Net tab can you see any Http error?

Comment: I can't see any errors

Comment: have you tried debugging your code? it might be a permission's problem but you claim it's not returning http error at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are writing to `bin` folder. It causes an application reload in IIS.
You can check this out by putting a break-point in `Application_Start`.

By changing the path to `App_Data` it works as expected. no delay.
`HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/app_data")`

Comment: Disabling Session State don't help. Same results.

Comment: @Lic can you share your project somewhere/ or create a sample project so i can check it out?

Comment: Thanks Ashkan, here you can download the project. I tried also with async/Task pattern but nothing, no improvement.
[link](https://files.fm/u/tja56qqc)

Comment: Thank you @Ashkan, I didn't imagine that if I write in `bin` folder the application reload in IIS. Bu it make sense.

Comment: @Lic, no problem, IIS watches for changes on bin Dir so if you change dlls or web.config, it can reload the app.